# Overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть таблица, имеющая в себе в качестве ячейки Select.
При низкой ширине экрана, я добавляю нижний scroll к таблице. Но этот scroll перекрывает Select[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого есть предложения, буду благодарен за ваши ответы

```css
.tables-component {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table {
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table > table {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 1320px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table > table > thead > tr > th {
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 38px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #226B4B;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table > table > thead > tr > th:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table > table > thead > tr > th:first-child {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table > table > thead > tr > th:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.tables-component > .foundation-table > table > tbody > tr > td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 13px MontserratMedium;
    border: 1px solid #E3E8F1;
    color: #3B3F61;
}
.tables-component > .conrols-table > table > thead > tr,
.tables-component > .conrols-table > table > tbody > tr {
    height: 38px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tables-component > .conrols-table > table > thead > tr > th > .add-column-in-table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3.5px;
    background-color: #226B4B;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media (min-width: 1440px) {
    .tables-component > .foundation-table {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}




.scrollbar-component {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.scrollbar-component::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #FCFCFE;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.scrollbar-component::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
}
.scrollbar-component::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #E3E8F1;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

/*   Select   */

.select {
    position: relative;
}
.select > .select-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    width: 380px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #3B3F61;
    font: 13px MontserratSemiBold;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #E3E8F1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    user-select: none;
}
.select > .select-container > span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.select > .select-container.default {
    color: #686B84;
    font: 13px MontserratRegular;
}
.select > .select-container.in-table {
    height: 52px;
    font: 13px MontserratRegular;
    color: #3B3F61;
    border: none;
}
.select > .select-container.default.in-table {
    color: #686B84;
    font: 13px MontserratRegular;
}
.select > .select-container.active {
    border: 1px solid #226B4B;
    z-index: 20;
}
.select > .select-container.in-table.active {
    z-index: 20;
    border-radius: 0;
    outline: 1px solid #226B4B;
    border: none;
}
.select > .select-container > div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.select > .select-container > div > .clear {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
}
.select > .select-container > div > .collapse {
    margin: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    fill: #686B84;
    transition: .3s;
}
.select > .select-container > div > .collapse.active {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    fill: #226B4B;
    transition: .3s;
}
.select > .list {
    padding: 35px 5px 6px 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    width: 360px;
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 10;
}
.select > .list.in-table {
    padding: 45px 5px 6px 14px;

}
.select > .list > .list-items {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
    z-index: 20;
}
.select > .list > .list-items > p {
    margin: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    padding: 8px;
    font: 13px MontserratSemiBold;
    color: #3B3F61;
    border-radius: 6px;
    transition: .1s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select > .list > .list-items > p:hover {
    background-color: #265243;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: .1s;
}
```

```html
<div class='tables-component'>
        <div class='foundation-table'>
            <table>
                <thead class='font-text6 white'>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='breed'>Порода</th>
                        <th class='height-rank'>Разряд высот</th>
                        <th class='thickness-step'>Ступень толщины (диаметр)</th>
                        <th class='business-trunks'>Кол. деловых стволов</th>
                        <th class='wood-trunks'>Кол. дровяных стволов</th>
                        <th class='trunks'>Общее количество стволов</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="select font-text2 blue-light">
                                <div class="select-container active default in-table">
                                    <span title="Выберите значение">Выберите значение</span>
                                    <div><svg class="collapse active" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" version="1" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48"><polygon points="5,30.9 8.1,34 24,18.1 39.9,34 43,30.9 24,12"></polygon></svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list in-table">
                                <div class="list-items scrollbar-component">
                                    <p>Договор аренды</p>
                                    <p>Лесная декларация</p>
                                    <p>Лесосека</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="g" id="2">
                                <option value="one">one</option>
                                <option value="two">two</option>
                                <option value="three">three</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class='in-table' type='text' placeholder='Введите значение' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Есть предложение: чтобы вы выложили свой код

Comment: В вашем коде в выпадающем списке ничего нет.

Comment: Там кода более чем на 1000 строк. Он не так важен, важна только идея. Код я умею сам писать

Comment: Выложите рабочий код. Необязательно выкладывать всю версию, добавьте руками элементы в выпадающий список, чтоб можно было увидеть баг и посмотреть стили через панель разработчика т.д.
С текущим видом вы могли и не выкладывать код, полезность от него 0.
Даже всю таблицу нет смысла выкладывать, достаточно 1 ячейки с селектором + столбец, чтоб растянуть его для появления прокрутки

Comment: возможно поможет свойство ```z-index```